# mysql single query for a single database table

Tags: mysql

i need to specify following in one query: It should include the `Activity_name` and `Child_ first_name` and `last_name` for each child registered for the specified Activity. There is (Football/Art/IT) activities in `Activity Table`(which has `primary_key` for each activity). What would be the query that would list children registered for Art activity? Children name's should be displayed in one column. Thanks.

Comment: Table structure please, table names & columns.

Comment: There is ACTIVITY, CHILD and CHILD ACTIVITY TABLES. ACTIVITY TABLE(activity_id[Primary Key], Activity), CHILD TABLE(child_id[Primary Key], child_name, child_gender, child_dob), CHILD ACTIVITY TABLE(activity_id[Composite Primary Key], child_id[Composite Primary Key]Activity/Day Of Week) Hope this is sufficient. Thank you

Comment: Just substitute `child activity` for `linktable` in my answer below. Note that the space in your table name may require some backticks around it. Do the same for the various field names as appropriate. If you are still not getting the desired output, post another comment for an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without providing your table structure, I cannot provide an accurate query.

However, if I were to design a set of tables that store a list of children, a list of activities, and a correlation between the two, it would consist of three tables named "children," "activities," and "linktable" in this example.

```
children
    id
    first_name
    last_name

activities
    id
    name

linktable
    child_id
    activity_id
```

`children` stores the names and information of every child, and a unique id. `activities` stores the names and relevant information about activities, as well as a unique id. Finallly, `linktable` may be something like "schedule" or "signups" in your system, and should link children to activities and allow for what is called a `many-to-many` relationship. In other words, one child may participate in many activities, and any activity may be engaged by many children.

The following query is an example of how to see which children are signed up for Art:

```
SELECT
    a.name, CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS child_name
FROM
    children c, activities a, linktable
WHERE
    linktable.child_id = c.id
AND
    linktable.activity_id = a.id
AND
    a.name = 'Art';
```

Comment: Based on table structure in your comment, you won't need the `CONCAT` method, since it doesn't appear first and last names are stored in separate columns: `SELECT a.name, c.child_name`